# Kubectl targets local cluster even when the current context is set to remote cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, azure-aks

I have local kubernetes cluster installed as a part of Docker for Windows. So when I run

```
kubectl get pods
NAME                                 READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
mytestapplication-64b546767f-hsd5s   1/1     Running   0          6d10h
```

Now I am running the following

```
az aks get-credentials --resource-group appxxx-dfaks-rg --name appxxx-dfaks
Merged "appxxx-dfaks" as current context in C:\Users\aus77_000\.kube\config
```

Checking the contexts information

```
kubectl config get-contexts
CURRENT   NAME                 CLUSTER          AUTHINFO                                   NAMESPACE
          appxxx-dfaks         appxxx-dfaks     clusterUser_appxxx-dfaks-rg_appxxx-dfaks
*         docker-desktop       docker-desktop   docker-desktop
```

Switching the context to `appxxx-dfaks`

```
kubectl config use-context appxxx-dfaks
Switched to context "appxxx-dfaks".
```

Now the current context is `appxxx-dfaks`

The problem is that kubectl keeps targeting my local cluster

```
kubectl get pods
NAME                                 READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
mytestapplication-64b546767f-hsd5s   1/1     Running   0          6d10h
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be because context `appxxx-dfaks` is using `cluster` which is the local cluster. You can verify which context is using what cluster using

```
kubectl config view --minify
```

Also run `kubectl get nodes` or `kubectl cluster-info` to verify what is the cluster actually being used by kubectl.

Check official docs [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - kubectl config view --minify returns remote cluster information. Same happens for kubectl get nodes or kubectl cluster-info.

Comment: Then you are connected to the remote cluster. What makes you believe that you are connected to local cluster?